# Error using airflow's DataflowPythonOperator to schedule dataflow job

Tags: airflow, dataflow

I am trying to schedule dataflow jobs using airflow's DataflowPythonOperator. Here is my dag operator:

```
test = DataFlowPythonOperator(
    task_id = 'my_task',
    py_file = 'path/my_pyfile.py',
    gcp_conn_id='my_conn_id',
    dataflow_default_options={
        "project": 'my_project',
        "runner": "DataflowRunner",
        "job_name": 'my_job',
        "staging_location": 'gs://my/staging', 
        "temp_location": 'gs://my/temping',
        "requirements_file": 'path/requirements.txt'
  }
)
```

The gcp_conn_id has been setup and it could work. 
And the error showed that the Dataflow failed with return code 1. The full log is as below.

```
[2018-07-05 18:24:39,928] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:108} INFO - Start waiting for DataFlow process to complete.
[2018-07-05 18:24:40,049] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: 
[2018-07-05 18:24:40,049] {models.py:1433} ERROR - DataFlow failed with return code 1
[2018-07-05 18:24:40,050] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: Traceback (most recent call last):
[2018-07-05 18:24:40,050] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py", line 1390, in run
[2018-07-05 18:24:40,050] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
[2018-07-05 18:24:40,050] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator.py", line 182, in execute
[2018-07-05 18:24:40,050] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: self.py_file, self.py_options)
[2018-07-05 18:24:40,050] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 152, in start_python_dataflow
[2018-07-05 18:24:40,050] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: task_id, variables, dataflow, name, ["python"] + py_options)
[2018-07-05 18:24:40,051] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 138, in _start_dataflow
[2018-07-05 18:24:40,051] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: _Dataflow(cmd).wait_for_done()
[2018-07-05 18:24:40,051] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py", line 119, in wait_for_done
[2018-07-05 18:24:40,051] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: self._proc.returncode))
[2018-07-05 18:24:40,051] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: Exception: DataFlow failed with return code 1
```

It seems there is a problem with the gcp_dataflow_hook.py, except for this there is no more info. Is there any way to fix this and is there any example of the DataflowPythonOperator?(I couldn't find any usage case out there so far)

Comment: `DataFlow failed with return code 1` seems to me that the very DataFlow throws an error, not the `gcp_dataflow_hook.py` or the `DataflowPythonOperator`. So you might need to look in the Cloud Console for errors regarding the data flow you are calling

Comment: I am facing the exact same problem, @Lisa.Z how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting the same error message but I think this may help.  The python Dataflow runner appears to terminate in a weird way that doesn't affect standalone Dataflow jobs but cannot be handled correctly by the DataFlowPythonOperator python airflow class.  I am in the process of submitting a ticket but here is a workaround that has solved my problem.  IMPORTANT! The patch must be applied to the Dataflow job not the airflow job.

At the top of the Dataflow job add the following imports

```
import threading
import time
import types   
from apache_beam.runners.runner import PipelineState
```

Next above your Dataflow code add the following.  This is mostly cut and paste from the main ~dataflow.dataflow_runner class with the commented edits

```
def local_poll_for_job_completion(runner, result, duration):
    """Polls for the specified job to finish running (successfully or not).
    Updates the result with the new job information before returning.
    Args:
      runner: DataflowRunner instance to use for polling job state.
      result: DataflowPipelineResult instance used for job information.
      duration (int): The time to wait (in milliseconds) for job to finish.
        If it is set to :data:`None`, it will wait indefinitely until the job
        is finished.
    """
    last_message_time = None
    current_seen_messages = set()

    last_error_rank = float('-inf')
    last_error_msg = None
    last_job_state = None
    # How long to wait after pipeline failure for the error
    # message to show up giving the reason for the failure.
    # It typically takes about 30 seconds.
    final_countdown_timer_secs = 50.0
    sleep_secs = 5.0

    # Try to prioritize the user-level traceback, if any.
    def rank_error(msg):
        if 'work item was attempted' in msg:
            return -1
        elif 'Traceback' in msg:
            return 1
        return 0

    if duration:
        start_secs = time.time()
        duration_secs = duration // 1000

    job_id = result.job_id()
    keep_checking = True  ### Changed here!!!
    while keep_checking:  ### Changed here!!!
        response = runner.dataflow_client.get_job(job_id)
        # If get() is called very soon after Create() the response may not contain
        # an initialized 'currentState' field.
        logging.info("Current state: " + str(response.currentState))
        # Stop looking if the job is not terminating normally
        if str(response.currentState) in (  ### Changed here!!!
                'JOB_STATE_DONE',  ### Changed here!!!
                'JOB_STATE_CANCELLED',  ### Changed here!!!
                # 'JOB_STATE_UPDATED',
                'JOB_STATE_DRAINED',  ### Changed here!!!
                'JOB_STATE_FAILED'):  ### Changed here!!!
            keep_checking = False  ### Changed here!!!
            break
        if response.currentState is not None:
            if response.currentState != last_job_state:
                logging.info('Job %s is in state %s', job_id, response.currentState)
                last_job_state = response.currentState
            if str(response.currentState) != 'JOB_STATE_RUNNING':
                # Stop checking for new messages on timeout, explanatory
                # message received, success, or a terminal job state caused
                # by the user that therefore doesn't require explanation.
                if (final_countdown_timer_secs <= 0.0
                        or last_error_msg is not None
                        or str(response.currentState) == 'JOB_STATE_UPDATED'):  ### Changed here!!!
                    keep_checking = False  ### Changed here!!!
                    break

                # Check that job is in a post-preparation state before starting the
                # final countdown.
                if (str(response.currentState) not in (
                        'JOB_STATE_PENDING', 'JOB_STATE_QUEUED')):
                    # The job has failed; ensure we see any final error messages.
                    sleep_secs = 1.0      # poll faster during the final countdown
                    final_countdown_timer_secs -= sleep_secs

        time.sleep(sleep_secs)

        # Get all messages since beginning of the job run or since last message.
        page_token = None
        while True:
            messages, page_token = runner.dataflow_client.list_messages(
                job_id, page_token=page_token, start_time=last_message_time)
            for m in messages:
                message = '%s: %s: %s' % (m.time, m.messageImportance, m.messageText)

                if not last_message_time or m.time > last_message_time:
                    last_message_time = m.time
                    current_seen_messages = set()

                if message in current_seen_messages:
                    # Skip the message if it has already been seen at the current
                    # time. This could be the case since the list_messages API is
                    # queried starting at last_message_time.
                    continue
                else:
                    current_seen_messages.add(message)
                # Skip empty messages.
                if m.messageImportance is None:
                    continue
                logging.info(message)
                if str(m.messageImportance) == 'JOB_MESSAGE_ERROR':
                    if rank_error(m.messageText) >= last_error_rank:
                        last_error_rank = rank_error(m.messageText)
                        last_error_msg = m.messageText
            if not page_token:
                break

        if duration:
            passed_secs = time.time() - start_secs
            if passed_secs > duration_secs:
                logging.warning('Timing out on waiting for job %s after %d seconds',
                                job_id, passed_secs)
                break

    result._job = response
    runner.last_error_msg = last_error_msg


def local_is_in_terminal_state(self):
    logging.info("Current Dataflow job state: " + str(self.state))
    logging.info("Current has_job: " + str(self.has_job))
    if self.state in ('DONE', 'CANCELLED', 'DRAINED', 'FAILED'):
        return True
    else:
        return False


class DataflowRuntimeException(Exception):
    """Indicates an error has occurred in running this pipeline."""

    def __init__(self, msg, result):
        super(DataflowRuntimeException, self).__init__(msg)
        self.result = result


def local_wait_until_finish(self, duration=None):
    logging.info("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!You are in a Monkey Patch!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
    if not local_is_in_terminal_state(self):  ### Changed here!!!
        if not self.has_job:
            raise IOError('Failed to get the Dataflow job id.')

        # DataflowRunner.poll_for_job_completion(self._runner, self, duration)
        thread = threading.Thread(
            target=local_poll_for_job_completion,  ### Changed here!!!
            args=(self._runner, self, duration))

        # Mark the thread as a daemon thread so a keyboard interrupt on the main
        # thread will terminate everything. This is also the reason we will not
        # use thread.join() to wait for the polling thread.
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
        while thread.isAlive():
            time.sleep(5.0)

        terminated = local_is_in_terminal_state(self)  ### Changed here!!!
        logging.info("Terminated state: " + str(terminated))
        # logging.info("duration: " + str(duration))
        # assert duration or terminated, (  ### Changed here!!!
        #     'Job did not reach to a terminal state after waiting indefinitely.')  ### Changed here!!!

        assert terminated, "Timed out after duration: " + str(duration)  ### Changed here!!!

    else:  ### Changed here!!!
        assert False, "local_wait_till_finish failed at the start"  ### Changed here!!!

    if self.state != PipelineState.DONE:
        # TODO(BEAM-1290): Consider converting this to an error log based on
        # theresolution of the issue.
        raise DataflowRuntimeException(
            'Dataflow pipeline failed. State: %s, Error:\n%s' %
            (self.state, getattr(self._runner, 'last_error_msg', None)), self)

    return self.state
```

Then when you start the pipeline use the convention 
(not the 'with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) p:' version)

```
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
```

Finally when your pipeline has been built use the following

```
result = p.run()
# Monkey patch to better handle termination
result.wait_until_finish = types.MethodType(local_wait_until_finish, result)
result.wait_until_finish()
```

**Note:**  This fix still won't fix the problem if you are running an airflow server v1.9 like I was with a 1.10 patch file.  The patch file function for _Dataflow.wait_for_done is not returning job_id and it needs too.  The patch for the patch is worse than above.  Upgrade if you can.  If you can't paste in the following code as headers to your Dag script with the latest file and it should work.  airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_api_base_hook.py, airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py, and airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator.py

Comment: What is your apache-beam version?

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
import threading
import time
import types   
from apache_beam.runners.runner import PipelineState
```

changed the with clause to `p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)` and I ended it with `result.wait_until_finish()`
My DAG succeeded